# System hook to look for an encrypted file instead

Tags: encryption, gnupg, gpg-agent, system-calls

How to setup a system hook so that whenever the content of `/path/to/file` is requested, the system does the following

1. First check if `/path/to/file` exists. Act normally if it does.
2. If it does not exist, look for `/path/to/file.gpg`. If the later does not exist, then act normally.
3. If the later does exist, call `gpg` and prompt the user to decrypt. If the decryption is successful, return the content of it to the original request.

---

#### Example

`rclone` looks for `~/.config/rclone/rclone.conf` whenever it is called. I wish to store only its encrypted version `~/.config/rclone/rclone.conf.gpg`. But I don't want to hack rclone so that it follows the description above. I believe this should be made general.

Comment: What version of Linux or what OS? Is this for a program you're writing?

Comment: You would most likely want to write some kind of Fuse overlay filesystem to do this.

Comment: I'm on archlinux with kernel 5.10.56-1-lts @music2myear.